# JqueryUI bounce hides element and moves it left and animate doesn't apply to child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to use the function called bounce and animate in the JqueryUI library and I'm facing 3 problems:

1) I use the following code to apply the bounce effect:

```
$('#element').toggle( 'bounce', { times: 3 }, "slow" );
```

But this hides the element after the finish of bouncing. How to avoid this behavior??

2) I have centered the element using `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;` but during bouncing the element is positioned to the left and ignores the margin auto.

3) I use the function animate to fade in background-color to an element using this code:

```
$('#element').animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFF99'}, 'slow');
```

For some reason this applies the animation effect till the first child div and not the whole box. For example:

```
<div id="element">
   <p>this paragraph will get animated but the child div will not</p>
   <form>
      <div id="child"></div>   
   </form>
</div>
```

This is a fiddle to explain the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/E5XvT/1/

Thanks

Comment: Could you pls set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: in jsfiddle i can load jquery but how to load the jquery UI?

Comment: If you select jQuery 1.9.1 then jQuery UI 1.9.2 is in the checkbox list below.  For other versions, use the "External Resources" tab :)

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E5XvT/

Comment: i revised it again: http://jsfiddle.net/E5XvT/1/

Comment: I've updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/fYggv/), missed the child div question.

Answer (score 3):

from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

> .toggle(): Display or hide the matched elements.

what you want is [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) :

```
$('#element').effect( 'bounce', { times: 3 }, "slow" );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/fYggv/)

You are explicitly setting a background color on your `#child`

```
background-color: white;
```

remove that line and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rusln answered #1...

To answer #2 use:

```
    <div id="element" align="center">...
```

To answer #3 use (in css)

```
    #child {
    background-color: inherit;
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: align attribute is deprecated.